# Write Permission for Apache

Tags: php, apache, permissions, directory

so I am writing this bit of code that needs to create a folder in a specified directory.

```
public function createFolder () {
    opendir("images/u"); 
    mkdir("/nick", 0755, true);
    if (false){
        echo "the directry could not be made";
    }//end if
}//end createFolder
```

The problem is that Apache lacks the necessary permissions to perform the mkdir function. Now, there has been at least one other question similar to this that has been answered, but I do not find the answer satisfactory. I would like to know how I give Apache permissions without opening my directory up to everyone (i.e. chmod 0777).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your `opendir` call does nothing, since you're not saving the result anywhere.
2. You're trying to create the directory `/nick`. I.e. **in the root folder**. You should certainly not be giving Apache permissions for the root folder. More likely your path is simply wrong. You either mean `./nick` as relative to the current working directory, or `__DIR__ . '/nick'` as relative to the file's path or some other directory. But simply: you're using the wrong path to create your directory.